# jQuery carousel entire slide changes with images/text/etc

Tags: jquery, html, css, tabs, carousel

I'm pretty new to jQuery but basically what I'm looking for is a script that can do the following:

[image: imgur.com/PYSAL.jpg]

The numbers will change the entire slide (image and text).

Can someone point me to a script that can do this?  Or something very similar, I'm just learning about JS.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a jQuery plugin that is similar.
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

It's very customizable..even has the options for external controls like the one in your screen shot.

You put the images/text in ListItem tags `<li>`:

```
    <ul> 
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/66/199481236_dc98b5abb3_s.jpg" alt="" />Birds</li> 
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/75/199481072_b4a0d09597_s.jpg" alt="" />Frogs</li> 
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/57/199481087_33ae73a8de_s.jpg" alt="" />Dogs</li> 
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/77/199481108_4359e6b971_s.jpg" alt="" />Cats</li> 
      <li><img width="75" height="75" src="http://static.flickr.com/58/199481143_3c148d9dd3_s.jpg" alt="" />Insects</li> 
    </ul>
```